# Advanced parameters immediately after SELECT statement in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm reasonably new to programming properly with MySQL, so forgive anything crass and unpleasant in my code.

I have a table (allocations) which has the following:

- id
- job_id
- user_id
- day
- hours

and some other fields, but they're not important.

I want to calculate the total HOURS each DAY, using this one query.

ie.

`SELECT SUM(hours where day=mon) AS hours_mon, SUM(hours where day=tue) AS hours_tue..`

Struggling with the correct Syntax, I'm fairly sure this is possible.

I'd really rather not use 5 queries or PHP loops as I would have done in the past.

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (untested)

```
SELECT 
  SUM(hours) as hours, 
  CONCAT('hours_',day) as day 
FROM table 
GROUP BY day
```

Comment: I get the following when I do this: `[SUM(alloc.hours)] => 56 [day] => mon` Which is all the day's hours added together..

Comment: Scratch that! The rest of my query was throwing up an eorror, this is bang on, thank you!

Comment: Any way to name the result variables dynamically? Like hours_mon..? `AS CONCAT('hours_',day)` or something?

Comment: sure, try the new example, it should work, still untested though

Comment: That's so almost right! Except that outputs 2 things, day and hours. I want the output NAME to be hours_[DAYNAME] and the value of that to be the hours. ie hours_mon = 8

Comment: well that would mean your creating columns where its propably better to return rows, if thats the output that you want you'd need the answer below but that would mean your actually doing a query per day which is not the most database friendly as this, which actually returns the same data. You'd be best off to rethink the way your getting the data from the query than to do it all in one row.

Answer (score 1):

select day, sum(hours) from allocations
    group by day

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(HOURS) AS HOURS_MON FROM ALLOCATIONS WHERE DAY=MON), (SELECT SUM(HOURS) AS HOURS_TUE FROM ALLOCATIONS WHERE DAY=TUE)...
```

Comment: Aww, you really think that repeating 7 days manually is the best solution available? :)